# How to create dynamically drop-down lists from rows in Excel

Tags: excel, dropdown

My Excel file has the following rows (example product filters). First column is the filter group and the second is a value:

[image: my rows]

and I am looking for a fast way to use these data in order to create dynamically dropdown lists. Based on the data above the drop-down lists are : Flavor, Type, Color

Could you please suggest me a way to do it? If there is not solution, I want to create from the data above the following grouped table in order to create drop-down lists manually:

[image]

Comment: https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/microsoft-office/how-to-add-a-drop-down-list-to-an-excel-cell/

Comment: Unfortunately this guide is useful to create a dropdown list without grouping the data first

Comment: Maybe this one? https://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal13.html

Comment: @JoelWiklund Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

Select the Column and go to Data Validation[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfDsA.png)

Choose List as Allowed Values[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tXEX.png)

For Source just select the cells where the allowed values are present[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttnM1.png)

Hit Ok and you're done.[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kuFq.png)